# Win 10 IoT Core for RPI usefulness without Win10 machine

Tags: raspbian, windows-iot, operating-systems

I got Win 10 IoT core on my RPi 3. I dont have a computer running Windows, therefore I cant really run the dashboard. Is the Windows 10 IoT OS still useful? Or should I just switch to Raspbian.

Comment: What do you intend to do with your Pi?

Comment: The usual reading data from some temp sensors and maybe hosting  a website.

Comment: As @Aslam says below, Raspbian would be the better choice in this case. How and why did you pick Windows IoT?

Comment: I bought a kit from Adafruit that said get started with Windows 10 IoT. Only in the box did it say I needed to have Win 10 on a PC. It sounds kinda obvious, but since I was able to get Visual Studio on mac, I thought I could get the Dashboard as well.

Comment: You may want to check the microsoft site for IoT as they have been expanding support for their development tools to other platforms and it may actually be possible (if not easy) to use/develop for IoT with out a Windows machine. However, you will have an easier time with Raspbian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You better switch to Raspbian as without Windows PC it is completely useless. You need Microsoft Visual Studio installed on a Windows 10 PC to install and run packages. 
As far as the usefulness is concerned you will not find any prebuild packages to run, you have to create your own software using Visual Studio IDE which is based on Universal windows platform.